# Show category name and new articles and display page numbers. What function to use

Tags: categories

Show category name and new articles and display page numbers. What function to use.

Ex.

cat name 1

- -listcat1 1 update
- -listcat1 2 update
- -listcat1 3 update
- -listcat1 4 update

cat name 2

- -listcat2 1 update
- -listcat2 2 update
- -listcat2 3 update
- -listcat2 4 update

pagination 1,2

paged=2

cat name 3

- -listcat3 1 update
- -listcat3 2 update
- -listcat3 3 update
- -listcat3 4 update

and paged=x

cat name x

- -listcatx 1 update
- -listcatx 2 update
- -listcatx 3 update
- -listcatx 4 update

thank